# Multiplication doesn't work well inside of for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, operators

It doesn't work , i did everything to fix it, but everytime i got same answer.. My functions work good as i see. But when i try to multiplication them in for loop, it doesnt work, i get tons of zero..

I've been working for fixing this more than 5 days, i didnt want to change my arrays in functions, but if it wont fix, then i delete arrays, and add more functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int noktalar[4][4][3] = {
        { {30, 50, 1}, {130, 40, 1},  {200, 40, 1},  {240, 45, 1} },
        { {35, 90, 1}, {100, 95, 1},  {220, 95, 1},  {245, 90, 1} },
        { {25, 160, 1}, {80, 170, 1},  {240, 150, 1}, {260, 140, 1} },
        { {30, 250, 1}, {130, 200, 1}, {220, 220, 1}, {300, 300, 1} }};
     int i, j, a, b, k = 1;
     float X, Y, Z;
     float tX = 0, tY = 0, tZ = 0;

     for (a = 0; a <= 10; a++) {
         for (b = 0; b <= 10; b++) {
             for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                 for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                     X = bezierx(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][2];
                     Y = beziery(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][2];    // this part doesnt work well...
                     Z = bezierz(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][2];               
                 }//--j for--   
             }//--i for--   
             printf("%d::::: %f -- %f -- %f \n", k, X, Y, Z);
             k++;
         }// --b for--
     }// --a for--

     getch();
     return 0;
}

// -----------------main-------------------
int bezierx(int a, int b, int i, int j) {
    float Xx;
    float u = (float)a / 10, w = (float)b / 10;
    float Uu = 1 - u, Ww = 1 - w;

    float uu[4] = { (float)pow(Uu, 3), (float)(3 * pow(Uu, 2) * u), (float)(3 * Uu * pow(u, 2)), (float)pow(u, 3) };
    float ww[4] = { (float)pow(Ww, 3), (float)(3 * pow(Ww, 2) * w), (float)(3 * Ww * pow(w, 2)), (float)pow(w, 3) };

    Xx = uu[i] * ww[j];

    //  printf(" x : %f -- \n ", Xx);

    return (float)Xx; 
}

int beziery(int a, int b, int i, int j) {
    float Yx;
    float u = (float)a / 10, w = (float)b / 10;
    float Uu = 1 - u, Ww = 1 - w;

    float uu[4] = { (float)pow(Uu, 3), (float)(3 * pow(Uu, 2) * u), (float)(3 * Uu * pow(u, 2)), (float)pow(u, 3) };
    float ww[4] = { (float)pow(Ww, 3), (float)(3 * pow(Ww, 2) * w), (float)(3 * Ww * pow(w, 2)), (float)pow(w, 3) };

    Yx = uu[i] * ww[j];

    // printf("y : %f -- ", Yx);

    return (float)Yx;
}

int bezierz(int a, int b, int i, int j) {
    float Zx;
    float u = (float)a / 10, w = (float)b / 10;
    float Uu = 1 - u, Ww = 1 - w;

    float uu[4] = { (float)pow(Uu, 3), (float)(3 * pow(Uu, 2) * u), (float)(3 * Uu * pow(u, 2)), (float)pow(u, 3) };
    float ww[4] = { (float)pow(Ww, 3), (float)(3 * pow(Ww, 2) * w), (float)(3 * Ww * pow(w, 2)), (float)pow(w, 3) };

    Zx = uu[i] * ww[j];

    //  printf("z : %f \n", Zx);

    return (float)Zx;
}
```

Comment: Could you fix your indentation?

Comment: Any particular reason you define `bezier*()` to return an `int` and not a `float`?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using a C compiler and not a C++ compiler? I am asking as this `float uu[4]={(float)pow(Uu,3),  ...` is not valid C.

Comment: @alk it's C compiler. how can i return float from bezier functions?

Comment: Just  change the definition to be `float bezierx(int a, int b, int i, int j) { ...` and add a corresponding declaration like  it `float bezierx(int, int, int, int);` before the function  is used, in your case that is *before* `main()`.

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir: Which C compiler is this please?

Comment: @alk i use Dev C++. i cant create float function, it says [Error] conflicting types for 'bezierz'

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir: you **must** declare the function before using it.  Move the `main` function after the other definitions.

Comment: I reindented the code.  Study how C code should be indented.  Use spaces around binary operators and after `,` and `;`.  This helps readability a lot.  Bugs are **much** easier to see in properly presented code.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for explanation and advices. You are hero in my opinion :) im not great i know, but you fix it quickly.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define `bezierx` and friends as returning `float` and either declare them before the `main` function or move their definition before the `main` function.

Note that you can simplify the code and should use `double` precision arithmetic instead of `float` for increased precision at no cost.  It is also better to write `x*x` and `x*x*x` instead of using `pow` for these simple integer powers to avoid precision loss.

Careful reading shows that there is no difference between `bezierx`, `beziery` and `bezierz`.  Use the same function.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

double bezier(int a, int b, int i, int j);

int main(void) {
    int noktalar[4][4][3] = {
        { {30, 50, 1}, {130, 40, 1}, {200, 40, 1}, {240, 45, 1} },
        { {35, 90, 1}, {100, 95, 1}, {220, 95, 1}, {245, 90, 1} },
        { {25, 160, 1}, {80, 170, 1}, {240, 150, 1}, {260, 140, 1} },
        { {30, 250, 1}, {130, 200, 1}, {220, 220, 1}, {300, 300, 1} }};
     int i, j, a, b, k = 1;
     double X, Y, Z;
     double tX = 0, tY = 0, tZ = 0;

     for (a = 0; a <= 10; a++) {
         for (b = 0; b <= 10; b++) {
             for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                 for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                     X = bezier(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][0];
                     Y = bezier(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][1];
                     Z = bezier(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][2];                
                 }
             }
             printf("%d::::: %f -- %f -- %f \n", k, X, Y, Z);
             k++;
         }
     }  
     getch();
     return 0;
}

double bezier(int a, int b, int i, int j) {
    double Xx;
    double u = a / 10.0, w = b / 10.0;
    double Uu = 1 - u, Ww = 1 - w;  
    double uu[4] = { Uu * Uu * Uu, 3 * Uu * Uu * u, 3 * Uu * u * u, u * u * u };
    double ww[4] = { Ww * Ww * Ww, 3 * Ww* Ww * w, 3 * Ww * w * w, w * w * w };

    Xx = uu[i] * ww[j];

    //printf(" bezier : %f -- \n ", Xx);

    return Xx; 
}
```

The code should be further simplified: `bezier` computes 8 coefficients of which only 2 are used for the final result.

Comment: i have one more question, in the for loop,it should be   
X = bezier(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][0];    
Y = bezier(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][1];    
Z = bezier(a, b, i, j) * noktalar[i][j][2];    
when i did that X and Y equal to each, Z is different, that is ok. But X and Y shouldnt be equal?

Comment: oh nvm, i 'm okey now